# "over one's head"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/gma/know-ukrainian-president-volodymyr-zelenskyy-010400045.html) there is a line,

> Holoborodko was often portrayed **as being in over his head**, but willing to fight corruption

What would bold part mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that he was struggling to cope with the situation he found himself in - like a person submerged in water deeper than their own height.